# how do I correctly paste multi-line xml snippet to github wiki when using markdown

Tags: github, markdown

I am trying to create a github wiki for my project. But I am unable to format a snippet from a Spring beans xml file, into this wiki. What is the proper way to do it? I tried using `pre` tag, `code` tag, the multiline code tag etc. But either it is not getting displayed at all or It displays everything in the same line.

Answer (score 245, accepted):

not 100% sure if this is the same thing or not, but I just setup some xml snippets in my readme.md and used the

```xml
<myxml>
   <someElement />  
</myxml>
```

notation.

Comment: think I may have found one that looked good and investigated how it was done, tbh not 100% I can remember

Comment: I think you also need a blank line before ```xml

Comment: I can confirm this solution works when I push a README.md to GitHub however I could not test it in a Markdown preview viewer, http://tmpvar.com/markdown.html.  It doesn't work there.

Comment: How can we also mix with other markup, say we want to make bold a part of the xml snippet. e.g. ** text ** displays the stars and not the text in bold.

Answer (score 29):

An old question, however, the solution has changed in the interim. Simply use the ```xml tag on modern mark-down implementations.

````
```xml
<your XML here>
.```
````

Example:

```xml
<one>
  <two>
  </two>
</one>
```

It's that simple and it works far better than embedding the XML as described above.

Comment: You could want to add an empty line before ```xml.
That would pretty format XML for some viewers.

Answer (score 21):

Replace all the less-than `<` and greater-than `>` symbols with `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively, then wrap in `<pre>` and `<code>` as before.