# XML to Markdown format conversion

Tags: xml, pandoc

I need to convert an XML format file to Markdown via Pandoc or otherwise if possible.
Following some recommendations, I have tried to convert it to the LaTeX format first and then to Markdown. All I have got in the Markdown file after conversion is just --------- (dashes).

The original content of the XML document to be converted is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<!--defining variable-->
<var-def name="http_response">
<!--passing the appropriate value from url_to_check column in input data file as a parameter for http plugin-->
<http url = "${url_to_check}"></http>
</var-def>
<!--exporting all original input columns-->
<export include-original-data="true">
<!--adding a new column with the http plugin result to the export file-->
<single-column name="http" value= "${http_response }"/>
</export>
</config>
```

Do you have any ideas how to do it? Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: maybe it's better to do it with a script (python, php)? What do you have and what do you want to receive, can you give an example?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this is just a piece of information which should be included in the documentation (as an example of configuration) and uploaded on GitHub

Comment: Why not use backquotes? https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#code

Comment: Maybe this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751548/how-do-i-correctly-paste-multi-line-xml-snippet-to-github-wiki-when-using-markdo

Comment: You wrote already the Markdown. You question is Markdown.

Comment: Thank you all for your assistance and advise :)

Answer (score 1):

Put the XML content between two sets of ``` — one set before the XML text and the other one after it

````
```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<!--defining variable-->
<var-def name="http_response">
<!--passing the appropriate value from url_to_check column in input data file as a parameter for http plugin-->
<http url = "${url_to_check}"></http>
</var-def>
<!--exporting all original input columns-->
<export include-original-data="true">
<!--adding a new column with the http plugin result to the export file-->
<single-column name="http" value= "${http_response }"/>
</export>
</config>
```
````